# Validation of Decimal in text Box

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to validate wether a number is a decimal in Visual Basic. The results I get when the number is valid the msgBox shows. When it is not valid, I don't receive the msgBox and the program crashes with an error message that number has to be less than infinity.

I tried adding another If Not IsNumeric(txt1.text) then -- But received the same results.

Where did i go wrong?

```
If IsNumeric(txt1.text) Then
  msgBox("good")
Else
  msgBox("not good")
End If
```

Comment: That code should work.  Can you post the exact error message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx) or [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx) instead of IsNumeric.

```
Dim result as Double = 0.0
if Double.TryParse(txt1.text, result) then
  ' valid entry
else
  ' invalid entry
end if
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the easiest version to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I have just had to write a function which restricts input to a text box to valid decimal values, and I came up with the following:

```
 Private Sub validateDecimalTextBox(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) handles myTextBox.keyPress
        Dim textBox As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
        If Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Or (e.KeyChar = "." And textBox.Text.IndexOf(".") < 0) Or (e.KeyChar = "-" And textBox.Text.Length = 0)) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

This should restrict user input to decimal values, allowing negative values as well.

If you restrict the user inputs then when you get the value out from the text box you can be more confident that it is valid.

This solution is not complete however as it would allow a user to enter just "-" in the text box which would (presumably) not be a valid input for you. Therefore you can use the solutions that others have mentioned and use any of the following in a sensible way.

```
double.parse, 
double.tryparse 
isNumeric()
```

My personal preference would be for isNumeric() but the choice is really up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore characters in the textbox's keypress event, like:

```
Private Sub txtValue_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtValue.KeyPress
        If Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
            If Not (e.KeyChar = vbBack) Then
               e.Handled = True
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

not sure which version of VB you're using, assuming it's .NET

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Textbox Keypress event. i.e

```
Private Sub Textbox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Textbox1.KeyPress
    If (e.KeyChar < "0" Or e.KeyChar > "9") And e.KeyChar <> "." And e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
        e.Handled = True
    Else
        If e.KeyChar = "." Then
            If Textbox1.Text.Contains(".") Then
                Beep()
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

I hope this helps.